# Change multiple elements using fadeIn(1000) but without waiting for another element to end fading

Tags: jquery

How to change color of one element using fadeIn(1000) and background of the another element using the same fadeIn(1000) but at the same time?

Comment: put elements in the same class and call fadeIn on that class

Answer (score 1):

Select them all together and just use one fadein ... Show some code

Comment: This is more suitable as a comment than an answer.

Answer (score 1):

To animate the colors, you also need the jQuery UI plugin to provide color animation.

```
$('#itemOne').animate({color:'#0ff'}, 1000);
$('#itemTwo').animate({backgroundColor:'#0ff'}, 1000);
```

For documentation at http://api.jquery.com/animate/ and http://jqueryui.com/animate/

Comment: This question is nothing to do with colours; `opacity` can be animated by plain jQuery

Comment: Hmm. The question does say "How to change the color of one element...".

Comment: Yeah this is what he needs.  And fadeIn() doesn't prove very effective for this situation.  Closed my jfiddle but there's no fade at all just instant color changes.

Comment: Maybe you're right; the question is too ambiguous. I take it to mean fading two elements above some existing ones (hence the use of fadein), which happens to change the colour because the new elements are a different colour.